# Left and Right Panel Navigation

Tags: jquery, mobile, panel, slidetoggle

Im attempting to work on a jquery navigation.  the navigation will be fixed open on desktop but will close on mobile device and opened on request.

My aim.

1) left panel to open and push the body content aside when on mobile device.

2) right panel to do exact same but on right side too.

I have created the html but im cant seem to find a jquery solution.

any ideas?

Cheers

Paul

http://jsfiddle.net/x3Rpk/

```
<div id="leftnav"> click to close and open on mobile device</div>
<div id="main-content">content her</div>
<div id="rightnav"> click close and open on mobile device</div>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfactory solution?

Answer (score 0):

Plugin for Bootstrap: http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/components/#navmenu-offcanvas

Plugin for Zurb Foundation: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html

Or if you prefer to build your own, the following uses jQuery and Bootstrap, but it could be built free of those.

Concept for DIY Build: http://scotch.io/tutorials/off-canvas-menus-with-css3-transitions-and-transforms

Demo of DIY Build: http://jsbin.com/xiviza/1/

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="site-wrapper">
    <div id="site-canvas">
      <div id="site-menu">
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="toggle-nav btn btn-lg btn-success" id="big-sexy"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#site-wrapper {
  background: pink;
  height: 1000px; /* Arbitrary. */
  overflow: hidden;  
}

#site-canvas {
  background: tan;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease all;
  transition: .3s ease all;
}

#site-menu {
  background: yellow;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -250px;
  padding: 15px;
}

#site-wrapper.show-nav #site-canvas {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
  transform: translateX(250px);
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('.toggle-nav').click(function() {
    $('#site-wrapper').toggleClass('show-nav');
  });
});
```